# Android Development Set Destination Systemetically From Marker Lat and Long

Tags: java, android

Hope my question is clear, given the example below in my code, I have 3 markers and therefore have 3 destinations, I have included a URI which opens up an intent activity which is the google maps app and starts the navigation which works fine except, the lat and long coordinates have been input manually on String uri and all the markers will lead me to the same destination when clicked, how can I input the destination variable so that I get the coordinates of whichever marker is clicked, I tried "LatLong" instead of the actual coordinates but that didn't work.

```
    static final LatLng ARCADIA = new LatLng(-25.746318, 28.221322999999984);
static final LatLng HATFIELD = new LatLng(-25.7487333, 28.238043199999993);
static final LatLng CENTURION = new LatLng(-25.8602778, 28.189444399999957);
private GoogleMap map;

private Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_store);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    //map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 5.0f ) );

        Marker aracdia = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ARCADIA).title("Arcadia")
                .snippet("35 Hamilton Street\n Tel: 076 7533 123\n click-for-directions")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
        Marker hatfield = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HATFIELD).title("Hatfield").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
        Marker centurion = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CENTURION).title("Centurion").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));



        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
                String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f (%s)", -25.746318, 28.221322999999984, "Navigating...");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){

// you determine which marker is clicked, maybe using the marker.getTitle();
//example: if marker.getTitle() is equals to Arcadia then set the latitude and longitude to arcadia lat and lng, 
//you can get the latitude of arcadia from marker position `aracdia.getPosition().latitude` or from the variable ARCADIA .. `ARCADIA.latitude`

//else if (another marker)..

//and finally set your uri and start activity
                        }
                });
```